# Select greater/less than time

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, time, mysqli

I have a database with the two time fields, fromtime and totime. Both are set as format Time, and contains xx:xx:xx

Lets say one of the rows has "fromtime" set to 00:10:00 and "totime" set to 00:23:00

How do I compare greater/less time in the php select query?
I have done it before, but now I can't find the fault

This is some of my code:

```
$thetime = date('H:i:s');

$sql = 'SELECT username FROM users WHERE fromtime < "'.$thetime.'" OR totime > "'.$thetime.'" LIMIT 1';
$stmt = $conn->query($sql);
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();

echo $row['username'];
```

Nothing is echo'ed, and there is no mysql error

UPDATE: error was that I set 10 o clock as 00:10:00, but that means 10 **seconds** after midnight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect your query isn't working because you need quotes around the time value:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE fromtime < '$thetime' OR totime > '$thetime' LIMIT 1";
```

Comment: Ah yes, that was just in this edit. In real code I use single quotes around the query and a lot of escaping. Now I edited it back, see the updated version

Comment: OK, cool. To help debugging can you echo out the value of `$sql`. Can you send the query directly to the database via a different means, e.g. using the console, phpMyAdmin or another client?

Comment: That helped me see the problem. My mistake! I have set the minutes and not the HOURS in my rows.. doh. Oh well, thank you :)

Comment: 00:10:00 is not 10 o clock :)

Comment: Ah - just spotted that! All fixed!